# different admin login result when setting DEBUG to false

Tags: django, debugging, admin

i encountered a very weird situation. Two VMs, one is rented from BandWagonHost, another one locates on my desktop, installed in VMware, same OS, cent OS 6.8. I use django-admin startproject to create the same project, then update the DEBUG from True to False in the settings.py file. Then start the development web server via 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'. For the one rented from BandWagon, I can open the admin login page without losing stylesheet, while for another one, the sytlesheet can't be found, so the admin login page seems very ugly, no style. Any one encountered same before?

Comment: try with `python manage.py runserver --insecure`

Answer (score 2):

You should run this command first!

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```